# how to format the variable x into format(platecode)

Tags: string, python-3.x

import string
with open('platenon.txt', 'w') as f:
   for platecode in range(1000):
    x =['A' + upper_char for upper_char in string.ascii_uppercase]
    f.write('KJA{0:03d}'.format(platecode))

Comment: how can i set string to print letter AA to AZ i tried this did not work                                                    "upper_chars = [chr(item).upper() for item in range(ord('aa'), ord('zz')+2)]
print (upper_chars)"

Comment: You should get an error message by calling the function ord with a string instead of an single character. Besides you don't use your variable upper_chars if you put it in quotation marks it will be evaluated as a string. But what is your question?

Comment: ord() can only process strings of length 1. ord('aa') and ord('zz') will not work. Can you specify what they desired output should look like? Maybe you can give an example?

Comment: example of what should print. kJA001AA,KJA002AB,KJA003AC...KJA999AZ,KJA001BA,KJA002BC...KJA999BZ...it should end at this KJA999ZZ

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you want to get a list which contains the strings 'AA' - 'AZ' ['AA', 'AB', 'AC', ..., 'AZ']?

```
import string
upper_chars = ['A' + upper_char for upper_char in string.ascii_uppercase]
```

---

To get a list with all strings from 'AA' to 'ZZ' you can use this in python3

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product

[''.join(c) for c in product(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_uppercase)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all combinations of two letters from 'AA' to 'ZZ':

```
import string
import product

list(''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=2))
```